# jQuery selector that gets all parent elements with less than n children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that can have a variable amount of `<td>` elements in each row, but with a max of 3 `<td>` elements per row. Say I wanted to select the rows with less than 3 `<td>` elements and assign them to a variable, is there a way I can select these rows with just jQuery? I know I can use something where I iterate through each row, like so:

```js
var rows = $("tr").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children().length < 3
});

rows.css("background-color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can do the same with just jQuery selectors and methods (i.e. `.siblings()` or `.parents()`)?

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/1advg20m/2/) a JSFiddle of the example I gave. I've looked for a similar question but couldn't find anything like this, so I'm hoping someone will have some ideas if this is possible.

Comment: you realize that without a colspan this is not valid html? each table row must have the same number of columns...

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Yeah I realize that. I probably should've added those attributes to the html, but I was just getting a simple example to show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use combination of [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) , [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo-class selectors.

```js
var rows = $("tr:not(:has(:eq(2)))");

rows.css("background-color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**FYI :** Depending on your need you can use [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) or [`:nth-of-type()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) instead of [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) method.

Comment: Upvoted as it's a possible solution, but personally I'd use `filter()` - it's much more easily readable. Also note that this doesn't just look at children. If you put a `<strong></strong>` around a value in the third row it no longer catches. OP needs to be wary if there is further child elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan :  he is already achieved the result using `filter`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan :  that would make it invalid markup..... even in that case using `nth-of-type()` instead may solve the problem

Comment: Yeah, `nth-of-type` would fix it, but then you're in to having a long unwieldy, almost regex-like, string selector. `filter()` still wins IMO :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan Yep this looks like what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan :  except `:has()` selectors all others are valid css selectors so it may be much faster... not sure :)

Comment: @NickG : glad to help you :)